# Archive error with every download

Tags: downloads

Ubuntu wont let me download anything at all,not from Ubuntu or the Internet.
Every time I try it keeps popping up this:

```
Archive:  /home/dave/Downloads/iTunes64Setup.exe
[/home/dave/Downloads/iTunes64Setup.exe]  
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/dave/Downloads/iTunes64Setup.exe or
          /home/dave/Downloads/iTunes64Setup.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/dave/Downloads/iTunes64Setup.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does it happen with anything besides .EXE files? This looks like the message that the archive manager pops up when it can't open Windows programs. The other thing you might try is installing WINE, though I can't promise how well iTunes will work in it.

Comment: Did you choose to automatically open downloaded files in your browser settings?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the icon, right click on the file in the Download folder and after installing [wine [image: Install wine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine), there should be an option that says "**Open With Wine Windows Program Loader**."

It worked for me, I am doing the same, downloading iTunes for Ubuntu.